# Use Ajax to POST and GET in the same PHP file (JSON)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to reach for a result passing by two steps :

- The first step I want to POST a value in PHP file from HTML(dropdown list):

this what I tried :

```
<select class="pam" >
<option value=""></option>
<?php
$conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=pame user=postgres password=";
$conn = pg_connect($conn_string); 
 $sql = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM espece order by nom_com  ASC ");

while($ligne_liste=pg_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$ligne_liste['id_espece'].'">'.$ligne_liste['nom_com']."</option>\n";
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

The JS code I used :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
      $('select.pam').change(function(){
         $.post ('/charta.php',
            {id_espece:$('select.pam').val()},
           success: function(){  
                  alert('success');
                  window.location = "http://localhost/charta.php";
            } 
            );
         });
    });
```

My PHP file :

```
<?php  

$user_id = isset($_POST["id_espece"])?$_POST["id_espece"]:"";
$user=conn ($user_id) // conn is a function who return an array from database
$js = json_decode( $user, true );
   ?>
  <?php 
   echo json_encode($js); ?>
```

the problem here is I get "NULL" for the value of $_POST ('id_espece') even though the value selected from the dropdown list; but When I replace the success function with :

```
function(res){ $('#txt').html(res); }
```

It returnes the result i want (JSON output) in the `<div id="txt"></div>`
but not in the PHP file when it return an error that `

> 'undefined index : id_espece'`

- The seccond step I want to GET the output of the same PHP file to HTML (div):

  If we supposed that PHP file works and sent a JSON form I tried to GET the result in JS file like this :

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/charta.php",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          var region = [];
          var sup = [];

          for(var i in data) {
              region.push("region " + data[i].nom_reg_12);
              sup.push(data[i].aq);
          }
          var chartdata = {
              labels: region,
              datasets : [
                  {
                      label: 'Superficie(m²)',
                      backgroundColor: 'rgba(77, 214, 104, 0.75)',
                      borderColor: 'rgba(77, 214, 104, 0.75)',
                      hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77, 214, 104, 1)',
                      hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77, 214, 104, 1)',
                      data: sup
                  }
              ]
          };

          var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

          var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'bar',
              data: chartdata
          });
      },
      error: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      }
  });
  });
  ```

to be sure that the second step work fine , I replaced `$_POST(['id_espece'])` with a default value and the PHP file return a JSON format not empty , so I think that the problem is in the first step ,  I don't know where is the problem exactly

Comment: you have a typo here:-  `$user_id = isset($_POST["is_espece"])?$_POST["id_espece"]:"";`  here it should be  `$_POST["id_espece"]` instead of `$_POST["is_espece"]`

Comment: get parameter cannot be reached by $_POST use $_REQUEST instead

Comment: Give your `select` a name attribute, `name="id_espece"`

Comment: @JayBlanchard he is using ajax to send data and there it is:- `{id_espece:$('select.pam').val()},` so the post varibale will be `$_POST['id_espece']` not `is_espece`

Comment: @AlivetoDie I was working with id-espece not is-espece i just edit my post

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: `$.post` is written incorrectly - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a form element in the `$_POST` array it must have a `name` attribute. Change your `select` element to have a name:

```
<select class="pam" name="id_espece">
```

In addition `$.post` doesn't have a `success` function as you have written it. The format should be this:

```
$.post ('/charta.php',
    {id_espece:$('select.pam').val()},
    function(data){  
          console.log(data);
          window.location = "http://localhost/charta.php";
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** : Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php) it seems you are sending a JSON format to the PHP so it can't parse it on $_POST, you need to get the complete body.

try this :

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.